# C Char pointers

Tags: c, pointers, char

Let us say we have a array of pointers:

`char *ptr[30];`

Now this works fine, and doesn't seems to do anything unexpected!
I can input names easily.

```
scanf("%s", ptr[1]);
scanf("%s", ptr[2]);
scanf("%s", ptr[3]);

printf("%s\n", ptr[1]);
printf("%s\n", ptr[2]);
printf("%s\n", ptr[3]);
```

My question is if a pointer can be used in this way to store end number of names, then why is malloc used.? and in this case ptr[1] does not point to the character in the input but to a new input itself.
for eg if ptr has mukul, ptr[1] should point to 'u'
and if space is not allocated when a pointer is declared like this, what are the limits.?

Comment: Also, it must be noted that the first element in an array is ptr[0].

Comment: Try doing something between `scanf`s and `printf`s. You should see some undefined behaviour.

Comment: yeah ptr[0] is definately there! Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 13):

The pointer *cannot* be used that way.  It might "work" for you sometimes by sheer chance, but using a pointer without allocating memory for it will cause **[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** - meaning that your program may behave erratically and give you unexpected results.

Remember, just because your program compiles and runs doesn't mean it is correct.  In the C language there is a whole class of errors known as "undefined behavior", many of which the compiler will happily let you do without complaining.  These include overwriting a buffer, using an uninitialized variable, or dereferencing a pointer that doesn't point to a legitimately allocated memory block.  Programs that exhibit undefined behavior may even appear to work normally sometimes - but they are usually very unstable and prone to crash.

Comment: Also please tell that declaration char *ptr[30] , tells that there is 30 character pointers ie it can point to 30 different characters because it is a pointer array or it can point to 30 different array of characters(in this case names)?

Comment: i mean it should point to 30 different characters but here it is being used to point to 30 different names is this correct.?

Comment: @Mukul, in C a `char*` usually points to a null-terminated array or sequence of characters (also known as a "string").  So `char *ptr[30]` is an array of 30 char pointers, or you can call it an array of 30 "strings."  Note that `char*` doesn't HAVE to point to a null-terminated array of characters - it can also point to a single `char`.  But in common usage, `char*` points to a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 4):

If you use what is in your example, you just owerwrite other locations what come after your `ptr` array. Most compilers should actually give at least a warning. Your program would crash on most systems, you were just very lucky.

Answer (score 3):

When you define a pointer like:

```
char *ptr = 0; // NULL pointer: dereferencing it will crash
puts(ptr);    // crash
```

You merely create a link to a place in memory:

```
ptr = "string"; // dereferencing it will show the string
puts(ptr);     // displaying "string"
```

So having an array of pointers merely creates a list of references to other variables.

To reference a place in memory, you *then* have to assign variables to your pointers, or allocate memory for each pointer.

Comment: so a pointer say char *c; can point to a character or it can point to an array of character..? what is more correct.? if it only points to one character then doing c++ and storing something again, it should overwrite!

Comment: A pointer can point to any size of data, not necessarily of the same type of the pointer. Whether or not the target is an array is up to you. Variables are memory places. Pointers are references to memory.

Comment: This is correct but doing pointer++ should always point to the next memory location. And if an array has been stored in the previous location this location should be proccupied?

Comment: When a pointer is incremented, it is incremented by the number of bytes of its type (that can be a lot of bytes for a long structure), and of course, you should only traverse this way the memory that has been previsouly allocated to prevent a crash from happening.

Answer (score 3):

You've allocated space for 30 pointers, but you haven't initialized them to point anywhere meaningful.  Unless you declared the array outside of a function, each element in the array will contain some random bit string that may or may not correspond to a writable memory location.  If we drew a picture, it would look something like this (all addresses are pulled out of thin air; don't assume this corresponds to any real architecture):

```
Item       Address       0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----       -------       ----  ----  ----  ----
ptr        0xbbc81230    0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
           0xbbc81234    0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
           0xbbc81238    0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
           ...
           0xbbc812a8    0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
```

where `0x??` represents a random byte value.  For the behavior you've described, each of the random values *just happens* to point to writable memory, and writing over whatever's stored there *just happens* to not have any immediate ill effects.

Bad juju: it *looks* like your code is working properly when in reality it's behaving very badly, and can lead to some nasty runtime problems elsewhere in your program that's a pain to debug.

You will need to explicitly set each element of the `ptr` array to point to a valid memory location before attempting to write through it.

Suppose we add the following code:

```
ptr[0] = malloc(strlen("foo") + 1);
strcpy(ptr[0], "foo");
ptr[1] = malloc(strlen("bar") + 1);
strcpy(ptr[1], "bar");
```

We've dynamically allocated some extra memory to hold a couple of strings, and stored the pointers to those new buffers to `ptr[0]` and `ptr[1]`.

Our picture would now look something like this:

```
Item       Address       0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----       -------       ----  ----  ----  ----
           0x80ff0000     'f'   'o'   'o'  0x00
           ...
           0x80ffcdc0     'b'   'a'   'r'  0x00
           ...
ptr        0xbbc81230    0x80  0xff  0x00  0x00
           0xbbc81234    0x80  0xff  0xcd  0xc0
           0xbbc81238    0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
           ...
           0xbbc812a8    0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
```

`ptr[0]` now contains the address of a buffer sized to hold 4 `char` values, and we copy the string "foo" to that buffer.  Similarly, `ptr[1]` contains the address of another 4-byte buffer that now contains the string "bar".